# Can Windows 7 x64 work with XPDM drivers ? or geforce cards work in TCC mode?

Tags: windows-7, cuda, windows-xp, gpgpu, windows-7-x64

I use GeForce cards for GPGPU computations with CUDA. A well known problem is that the WDDM introduces a huge overhead on the CPU side, leading to a non-negligible latency increase.

Also I need to run these programs in MS Windows environment and I would like to do it in modern systems like Windows 7 x64.

So, is there any way I can make Windows 7 work with XPDM? I think it was possible in Vista and maybe even in Windows 7 x86 (not sure tho).

TCC mode is only available for Tesla products (products I can not afford and neither I need the features they offer over GeForce). Is there any workaround for making a GeForce work in TCC mode?

Thanks in advance,
Javier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NVIDIA GPU driver for win 7 must be in either WDDM mode or TCC mode. There are no other possibilities for that driver. And as you've stated, TCC mode is not available with GeForce branded GPUs, so you are limited to WDDM mode.

Comment: so the only option I have is downgrade to winXP 64bits? (if i want to stay in MS environment I mean)

Comment: Certainly winXP is not using WDDM.